# TreeTableView JavaFX 8: I need to make one of columns to use TextFIeld and ChoiceBox when editing

Tags: java, javafx, cell

I have TreeTableView with 2 columns, so I want to be able something like that:
user double click in cell ->  Someclass.getType() returns type of editing field ->in cell I see this type of editing field(TextField or ChoiceBox)

wnen I need to use TextField only, i can use someshing like that

```
TreeColumn1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn());
TreeColumn1.setOnEditCommit(firstColumnCommitHandler);
```

commitHandler:

```
private EventHandler<TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent<SomeClass, String>> firstColumnCommitHandler = event -> {
    final SomeClass item = event.getRowValue().getValue();
    item.setVariable(event.getNewValue());
};
```

but i need different types, and have no idea howto do this

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement the table cell yourself, and display the appropriate components when you go in and out of editing state. Here's a basic idea. The `ChoiceBox`s look odd, you may need to work with some CSS to get them looking correct. In this example, if the box in the first column is checked, the second column will use a `ChoiceBox` for editing; otherwise it will use a `TextField`.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithVaryingEditor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i)).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        TableColumn<Item, Boolean> fixedCol = column("Fixed", Item::fixedProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(fixedCol);
        fixedCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(fixedCol));

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = column("Name", Item::nameProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);

        nameCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Item, String>() {
            private TextField textField = new TextField();
            private ChoiceBox<String> choice = new ChoiceBox<>();

            private boolean ignoreChoiceBoxChange = false ;

            // anonymous constructor:
            {
                choice.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (! ignoreChoiceBoxChange) {
                        commitEdit(newValue);
                    }
                });
                choice.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                    if (! isNowFocused) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                });
                choice.showingProperty().addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
                    if (! isNowShowing) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                });
                textField.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(textField.getText()));
                textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                    if (! isNowFocused) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (isEditing()) {
                    updateEditor();
                } else {
                    updateText();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void startEdit() {
                super.startEdit();
                updateEditor();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelEdit() {
                super.cancelEdit();
                updateText();
            }

            @Override
            public void commitEdit(String item) {
                super.commitEdit(item);
                updateText();
            }

            private void updateEditor() {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                int index = getIndex();
                Item item = getTableView().getItems().get(index);
                if (item.isFixed()) {
                    ignoreChoiceBoxChange = true ;
                    choice.getItems().setAll(getItem(), "Choice 1", "Choice 2");
                    choice.getSelectionModel().select(getItem());
                    setGraphic(choice);
                    choice.show();
                    ignoreChoiceBoxChange = false ;
                } else {
                    textField.setText(getItem());
                    setGraphic(textField);
                }
            }

            private void updateText() {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                if (isEmpty()) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(getItem());
                }
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final BooleanProperty fixed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        public final BooleanProperty fixedProperty() {
            return this.fixed;
        }

        public final boolean isFixed() {
            return this.fixedProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFixed(final boolean fixed) {
            this.fixedProperty().set(fixed);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain ur code? cause i use fxml file and controller, and there a lot of code in `class extends Application`, so i can have a lot of problems trying to understand this. If y can, write this code like u use controller) thx

Comment: The only relevant part is `nameCol.setCellFactory(...)`. Just do that in your controller's `initialize()` method.